# Table in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to show data in table from a website in my windows phone app.I am planning to use grid.row and grid.column properties.
Is there any other way to do this?Suggest me some samples

Comment: How much data will you need to display? will the user need to be able to scroll?

Comment: ya..long table has to be displayed